# Swift generic subclass of regular class "cannot convert value of type to expected argument type"

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, types, swift3

I am trying to create a subclass with a generic type that can be passed into a completion block, but am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(ModelListResponse) -> ()' to
>   expected argument type '(APIResponse) -> ()'

Parent class:

```
import ObjectMapper

class APIResponse: Mappable {
    var status: String!
    var message: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        status <- map["status"]
        message <- map["message"]
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
import ObjectMapper

class ModelListResponse<T: Mappable>: APIResponse {
    var data: ModelList<T>?

    required init?(map: Map) {
        super.init(map: map)
    }

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map: map)
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}
```

Then I have a function definition:

```
 func _GET(path: String, parameters: Parameters, completion:@escaping (APIResponse) -> ())
```

to perform a request.

And I'm trying to call it like so:

```
// error is on this line
self._GET(path: "/rest/posts", parameters: parameters) { (response: ModelListResponse<Post>) in
    // ...
}
```

Isn't a `ModelListResponse` an `APIResponse`?  I'm confused about why it cannot be converted.

**Update**

---

Well I managed to get around the issue by using a generic.  Though I have no idea why this is acceptable and the above code does not work. Here is my solution:

```
func _GET<T: Mappable>(path: String, parameters: Parameters, completion:@escaping (T) -> ()) { }
```

I'll leave it open for now to see if anyone knows why.